# The method is undefined for the type JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

So I am trying to create a simple program that prints out a rectangle but I am having this problem and I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsEditor extends JPanel{
    
    public void drawShape(Graphics g) {
        super.drawShape(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 120, 150);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        GraphicsEditor ga = new GraphicsEditor();
        
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        frame.add(ga);
    }

}
```

The error is when I am trying to add the `super` in here:

```
public void drawShape(Graphics g) {
            super.drawShape(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawRect(100, 100, 120, 150);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JPanel` has no `drawShape(Graphics)` method, so calling the 'super' method makes no sense. When you think you're overriding a method, be sure to add the `@Override` notation to get a compiler warning when the method is incorrectly spelled, uses the wrong arguments, or is just entirely non-existent (as is the case here).

The correct way to go about this is to override the `paintComponent` method, call the (existing) super method, then immediately call the `drawShape` method with the `Graphics` instance provided to the `paintComponent` method.

This is the result when the GUI is shrunk down:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsEditor extends JPanel {
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawShape(g);
    }
    
    // @Override // does NOT override an existing method! 
    public void drawShape(Graphics g) {
        //super.drawShape(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 120, 150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        GraphicsEditor ga = new GraphicsEditor();

        frame.setSize(280, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(ga);
    }
}
```